# PyCharm autocomplete, list of types

Tags: python, autocomplete, casting, pycharm, heredoc

How I can tell with `Docstring` to **PyCharm** that return type is the list of `SomeClass` instances?

Tried out: `@rtype [SomeClass]`, but it acts only as `list`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def do_something():
    """
    @rtype: list of SomeClass
    """
    pass
```

Works well, interprets return value as list and autocompletes `SomeClass` methods when accessing `list` element.